# KDE Neon 18.04 - Firefox not setting as default browser

Tags: kde, firefox, kde-neon

I did a clean install of KDE Neon this week and I noticed Firefox is not *really* set as default. When I go in system settings I see it is set. When I open a .html file or click on a link, it opens Firefox.

[image]

But when I go in Firefox preferences, it is not detected as default:

[image]

Additionally, I cannot open my Firefox Bookmark with Krunner (which is very annoying), but I think the two problems are related.

How could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

### It's something with an environment variable:

I have the same problem and it seems an issue with KDE itself. I've found that the whole problem is related to the following environment variable:

```
GTK_USE_PORTAL
```

### To fix:

As we all known, KDE works on QT and it's probable something with GTK on Firefox. To fix the issue, one must edit the following file:

```
/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

And on the first `Exec` line within the file, you have to add `env --unset=GTK_USE_PORTAL`, in order to execute Firefox in a proper way. So the line on the file have to be as follows:

```
Exec=env --unset=GTK_USE_PORTAL /usr/lib/firefox/firefox %u
```

After that **you must reboot** and then, open your firefox settings and try to set it as your default browser.

Comment: Thanks, did work for me - though the change had to be made under /home/usr/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop

Comment: You're right! It's very anoying to do this after a while too, still happens after a year (or maybe more).